# Circles and shaded areas with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw  this with TikZ with the inner of the 'triangle' being shaded (north west lines)

I have no idea how I can do this. Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw[densely dashed] (-1,0) arc (360:0:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

This is not really much, sorry :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the curves of the triangle can be cosmetic, then you can just use `to[bend right=15]`.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw (340:1) arc (340:200:1);
\draw[dotted] (200:1) arc (200:180:1);
\draw[dotted] (340:1) arc (340:360:1);
\filldraw[pattern=north west lines,line join=round] (90:1) 
  to[bend right=15] (.5,0)
  -- (-.5,0)
  to[bend right=15] cycle
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! What parameters do I have to change if I want the cusp above become more sharp?

Comment: @mathmarseille As in accentuate the curve? You can increase the number in `to[bend right=15]` to whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you! What can I do if I want to draw not the whole circle but only the circle segment 340 to 200°? And is it also possible to end this with ... ?

Comment: @mathmarseille See edit. What do you mean end it with ... ?

Comment: I want to indicate that the circle proceeds, so the ...

Comment: @mathmarseille you mean like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bNejF.png)?

Comment: Yes but with points and not dashed:)

Comment: @mathmarseille See edit.